# Check for integers of strings in a list and add them

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is that I have to write a function to check a list that contains numbers and strings, extract the number from each string and then add the numbers together.

```
my_list = ['0852eqh', '2245y4ng5b7y1223a8', 'r05o1gubbb58ay7n1', '7o2', '59owo7o23sb0795gl', 'h1v0961676mt', '1586z18c4p15', '06lx98371xf266g', '77zx50b4', 't983', '5kk6oa3m899oz6w', '3r6920ay486165', '739n1d4', '09m6056w0wa883', '32b5o4l91l9f5', '586qc77ef9b2a22rprh5', 'wsekkq7k', '59s38u54hbt', 'v04mqgq06n216bo', 'zjc', '2967187o', '2o75bz705u641d1tind', 'e8ett1k00qia', '8c16n03k6993936cymwg', '0711m5g6y', '65bu39zsbkm8', '504iv1nr7g7y9', '778538pe0cfikk', 'nr2v267qxvvhsp92395i', '3guc0ey94j7ivh314ye0']
```

so for example the first string will give me `852`, second will `224545712238` and then get the sum of all the numbers extracted add them to the list.

This is what I have so far:

```
def check(list):
    res = [ ]
    i = 0
    for (i) in (list):
        if i .isdigit():
            (res.append(i))
    print (res)
```

Edit
So i tried this:

```
def check(list):
res = []
for word in list:
    s = ''
    for char in word:
        if char.isdigit():
            s += char
    res.append(int(s))
return sum(res)
```

list= ['0852eqh', '2245y4ng5b7y1223a8', 'r05o1gubbb58ay7n1', '7o2', '59owo7o23sb0795gl', 'h1v0961676mt',
'1586z18c4p15', '06lx98371xf266g', '77zx50b4', 't983', '5kk6oa3m899oz6w', '3r6920ay486165', '739n1d4',
'09m6056w0wa883', '32b5o4l91l9f5', '586qc77ef9b2a22rprh5', 'wsekkq7k', '59s38u54hbt', 'v04mqgq06n216bo',
'zjc', '2967187o', '2o75bz705u641d1tind', 'e8ett1k00qia', '8c16n03k6993936cymwg', '0711m5g6y',
'65bu39zsbkm8', '504iv1nr7g7y9', '778538pe0cfikk', 'nr2v267qxvvhsp92395i', '3guc0ey94j7ivh314ye0']

print(check(list))

now im getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "C:/Users/n-soze/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/checkdig.py", line 20, in 
print(check(list))
File "C:/Users/n-soze/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/checkdig.py", line 8, in check
res.append(int(s))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you to get what you want

```
def check(l) :
res = []
for word in l :
    s = ""
    for character in word :
        if character.isdigit() :
            s += character
    if s == '':     #to handle case when no number is found in the string
        s='0'
    res.append(int(s))
return sum(res)
 

l = ["hey11" , ",12","how13","a1r4e","1you5"]
print(check(l))
```

here we first traverse the list and all characters of each word of the list to build list `res` this list stores number generated from the corresponding word .
for instance if `l[1] = "1h2e3y"` , then `res[1]` will be equal to 123
At the end we just return sum of the list res , by `return sum(res)`

Comment: hey i keep getting an error when i try to solve my list

Comment: @froze I have updated the code to handle the case which was giving the error . Error was due to converting empty string to number .

Comment: hey thanks, it worked like a charm thank you, your explanations were very helpful